# Element type invalid, when using Flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Please have a look at the following class. As soon as I use a FlatList (or List), I get the error: "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of 'Userlist'"

When I search for this error, it usually has to do with missing wrong imports. I think, my imports are correct?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, Text, Navigator, Alert, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { List, FlatList, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import FBUsers from '../../firebase/FBUser'

export default class Userlist extends React.Component {
    fbUser = new FBUsers();

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);

       this.state = {
         lastRefresh: '',
       }
    }



    refresh() {
        this.setState({lastRefresh: Date(Date.now()).toString()});
    }

    // buildUserList() {
    //     var users = this.fbUser.getUserList();
    //     return users;
    // }


    renderRow ({ item }) {
    return (
      <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        title={item.name}
        subtitle={item.subtitle}
        avatar={{uri:item.avatar_url}}
      />
    )
  }

  render () {
    var list = [
      {
        name: 'Amy Farha',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
        subtitle: 'Vice President'
      },
      {
        name: 'Chris Jackson',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
        subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
      }
    ]

    return (
      <List>
        <FlatList
          data={this.list}
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          keyExtractor={item => item.name}
        />
      </List>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: > Element type is invalid: expected a string... isn't this just the first part of the error? doesn't it say what it got ? ie: expected string, got undefined

Comment: I am sorry - now I completed the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `FlatList` from `react-native`. That's why you're getting this error. Use this code.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, Text, Navigator, Alert, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class Userlist extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lastRefresh: '',
    }
  }

  refresh() {
    this.setState({ lastRefresh: Date(Date.now()).toString() });
  }

  // buildUserList() {
  //     var users = this.fbUser.getUserList();
  //     return users;
  // }


  renderRow({ item }) {
    return (
      <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        title={item.name}
        subtitle={item.subtitle}
        leftAvatar={{ 
          source: { 
            uri: item.avatar_url 
          } 
        }}
      />
    )
  }

  render() {
    var list = [
      {
        name: 'Amy Farha',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
        subtitle: 'Vice President'
      },
      {
        name: 'Chris Jackson',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
        subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
      }
    ]

    return (

      <FlatList
        data={list}
        renderItem={this.renderRow}
        keyExtractor={item => item.name}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: My pleasure. :)